# Is it safe to make ubuntu look like mac os?

Tags: macosx

i am new to Ubuntu. i just wanna know, is this safe to do??
https://youtu.be/hQDhTIX4k7s

Comment: All you need is a yes or no? What do you mean with "is it safe"? It is software made by humans. Humans make mistakes.  But as we all make backups.... not a lot will go wrong if it does go wrong.

Comment: Maybe you should spend some time getting used to Ubuntu before you decide to make it look like MacOS?  Perhaps you will like what you see?  Personally, I don't think blindly following a YouTube video or a web page made by someone you don't know is a very good idea.  That's just general advice and not specific to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

### Maybe yes. Maybe no.

Generally, it's safe in the sense that it's unlikely to introduce malware to your system. But that's not a guarantee -- there are instructions there to install random software from github. We don't know what are in those files.

- Pro Tip #1: Know what you are installing.

Generally, it's NOT safe in the sense that it won't break your system. It probably won't break your system today. But eventually it might. Gnome changes a lot from release to release, and there is no guarantee that your changes will keep working or will remain compatible.

- Pro Tip #2: Know how to revert every change you make. Smart folks keep notes.

Also, while it may look great, it won't truly behave like MacOS. It will behave like Linux wearing a MacOS costume. MacOS applications won't work. HFS+ files will have permission problems. MacOS settings and behaviors simply won't be there at all. A user familiar with MacOS might get frustrated --even confused-- by those little differences unless you prepare them in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of excellent responses already orbiting around the potential meanings of "safe", but I feel I can add a little here.

I don't have time at the moment to watch the full video, but if all you're generally doing is altering the appearance of GNOME, you shouldn't have too much to worry about. With Timeshift, you're generally also protected from goofing and losing your desktop environment, so it should be just fine.

It's important to remember that flexibility is part of the GNOME standards and general culture (as it is for other desktop environments like KDE Plasma and XFCE). Not everyone works well in the same environment, after all. So altering things like the menu layout is no more dangerous than, say, changing your desktop wallpaper.

The only thing I've seen that is worth commenting on is the "git clone" part. Github is a private website, and it is not a part of your distro in itself; anybody can upload anything to such services. So, when you get to the part about executing shell files ("*.sh"), you want to make absolutely certain that you trust where these files are coming from. Personally I would shy away from that, but it's perfectly plausible that it's innocuous.

Unless we looked at the actual contents of the shell files, it's very difficult to say how safe this is. Politely, if you're very new to Ubuntu, I might suggest playing with the settings yourself and seeing if you can find something that works well for you, before handing control over to an unknown script writer. Even if it's well meaning, there's always the possibility that a dependency mismatch, or other subtle change, is going to prevent things from working out; with the UI tools you don't usually need to worry about that.

If you do proceed, you should most certainly use Timeshift so that you'll be able to reset any damage; and even then, using it isn't without its time and effort cost.